# Disable links after page load in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a bad problem in jquery

I have a link in Div . When click on link the JQuery Function run.
But when i load this Div on other Div the link not working.

How can i fix it?

thanks

This is Div 1

```
<div id="top_menu">
```

This is Div 2

```
<div id="detail_menu">
    <a href="#personal-detail"><div id="personal-detail" class="personal-detail"></div></a>
    <a href="#family-detail"><div id="family-detail"></div></a>
    <a href="#address-detail"><div id="address-detail"></div></a>
    <a href="#account-detail"><div id="account-detail"></div></a>
    </div>
```

And This is JQuery function.

```
$(".personal-detail").click(function(){
    fajaxcontent(".user-detail","user-forms.php .users-option");
});
```

When Div 2 load on Div 1 . The function does not working
I load with this code.

```
$("Div1").load("Div2");
```

Comment: please post code - post link to a jsfiddle would be best

Comment: If you're using the AJAX methods to load contents of other page then scripts won't be loaded, you'll have to rebind the events..

Comment: Why do you use the load() ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you're doing, but it looks to me that, as mentioned, you need to use jquery 'live'

```
$(".personal-detail").live('click', function(){
    fajaxcontent(".user-detail","user-forms.php .users-option");
});
```

I believe this should work, forgive me if I've misunderstood the issue.

Comment: Very very  very very very thanks. I love you jamie. By .live my problem fixed. thanks

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("Div1").load("Div2");
```

This code is just loading content from the web and putting it onto the page. It's not binding any click handlers, etc. You have to take care of it manually (run that jquery function you posted).